# What's the difference between ASP.NET DynamicData and IronSpeed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data, ironspeed

Will the new commer (DynamicData) relplace the old one (IronSpeed)? They seem to have overlap functionality?

Answer (score 3):

WEll, for one - ASP.NET Dynamic Data is part of the basic ASP.NET package that you get - IronSpeed is a commercial add-on with a fairly hefty price tag.

So I would assume for a lot of folks, this question is a no-brainer as long as ASP.NET Dynamic Data is halfway useful (and it is!).

Plus - the two are really totally different beasts - this is like comparing apples to elephants. IronSpeed is a complete web app generation package - a lot more than "just" scaffolding your tables with a base admin UI, I would say.

ASP.NET Dynamic Data on the other hand isn't a complete application framework - it's a great tool to get basic admin and/or prototype UI's up and running, but it's not the finished app, really.

Marc

Comment: IMHO, it's hard to be believe that a generation tool that can generate entire application for developer. It should be 'halfway useful', focus on 1 area it can do best, and most important it must provide us an easy way to customize, it seem that DynamicData is more flexible?